# How do I reference an ItemProperty of a generic VBA Object variable by the property name?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an Outlook 2003 VBA application that includes something like the following code in a particular class:

```
Sub SaveAttributes(objMail as Outlook.MailItem)
Dim Field As String  
Dim SaveForLater As String  

Field = "Subject"  
SaveForLater = objMail.ItemProperties(Field).Value  

...  

End Sub
```

I'd like to extend the app to handle MeetingItems, etc, and I thought to modify the code like so:

```
Sub SaveAttributes(objGeneric as Object)  
...
```

This modification generates a runtime error 91, 'Object variable or With block not set',  at the line assigning SaveForLater.

The runtime error disappears if I modify that line like so:

```
SaveForLater = objGeneric.ItemProperties.Item("Subject").Value
```

But it oddly reappears if I modify that line like so:

```
SaveForLater = objGeneric.ItemProperties.Item(Field).Value
```

Why do these lines behave differently?  And what is the proper way to reference a generic Object's item properties by name, where the name is a string variable?

Comment: Have you tried using Variant instead of String for your "Field" variable ?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
Sub SaveAttributes(objGeneric As Object)
    Dim Field As String
    Dim SaveForLater As String
    Dim itemProps As Outlook.ItemProperties
    Dim itemProp As Outlook.ItemProperty

    Field = "Subject"

    Set itemProps = objGeneric.ItemProperties
    Set itemProp = itemProps.Item(Field)

    SaveForLater = itemProp.Value

End Sub
```